# How to take input on console while using sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to ask name of the player before running my sfml window. After user enters the name on console my sfml window appears but on that window i am unable to perform movement. And this problem only occurs if i take input from user on console otherwise movement was working accurate.

i want that my movement on my sfml window works,but it is not working. Also there is no problem in taking input i have checked it. The problem is only in movement.

Comment: Read input from console (`std::cin`) normally first. Then do all the SFML initialization and enter the SFML event loop. If you want further hlep with your code, please create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you want to be able to detect and read input from standard input while running the main SFML event loop, you have to use OS-specific functionality, suitable abstracted to fit SFML (if SFML doesn't already have it) to poll or detect console input events. You can't use normal `std::cin` input in the main event loop, it will block the program.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.